# Are quantum numbers always integers?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, conventions

Quantum numbers are integers for lots of systems. For example, for a particle in an infinite well
$$E_n = E_1 n^2 \text{ with } n = 1, 2, 3\ldots$$

for a quantum harmonic oscillator $$E_n = (n + \frac12) \omega \hbar \text{ with } n = 0, 1, 2, 3\ldots$$

for a quantum rotor $$E_J = \frac{\hbar^2}{2I}J(J + 1)$$

and for the hydrogen atom: $$E_n = \frac{E_1}{n^2} \text{ with } n = 1, 2, 3\ldots$$

But in this [finite well example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well#Finding_wavefunctions_for_the_bound_state), with no exact solutions, there are three bound states for  $v_n = 1.28$, $2.54$ and $3.73$.

The quantum numbers can be seen in a sense as integration constants of the Schrödinger Equation (with the normalisation constant as the second integration constant).

*Are the energy quantization numbers always integers or does that depend on the potential function* $V(r)$?

Comment: Observe that e.g. the spin quantum numbers are conventionally *half-integers*, not integers. Also observe that you could redefine $n' = n\omega$, so you have $n'$ not as an integer. It's just convention.

Comment: If you're asking if the energy levels are always *equally spaced*, then that of course depends on the potential (and they aren't equally spaced already for the hydrogen atom).

Comment: No, I understand the energy levels aren't necessarily equidistant, see also some of the examples I gave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, they are not.**

As [ACuriousMind](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/50583/acuriousmind) pointed out above, quantum numbers are just convention. They may be integers, real numbers, whatever depending on the problem discussed. Note that for example in quantum optics, coherent states $|α\rangle$ are defined in terms of complex quantum numbers, $α\in\mathbb C$. How they translate to actual physical quantities (*which they are not*) is to be defined in each case.

If turning somebody else's comment into an answer is bad style, please don't downvote, I'll delete the answer then.
Edit: Seems it's not.

Comment: Turning someone else's comment into an answer is not bad style, cf [this Meta.SE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157889/) and related Linked posts.

Comment: A float is a representation of a real number in a computer program - you should just write "real." Is $\alpha$ a quantum number? I suppose it characterizes a set of eigenfunctions, but it isn't quantized.

Comment: The α are actually the eigenvalues of the annihilation operator. Maybe calling them "quantum numbers" is wrong. Plz suggest an edit if you like.
Some info on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states#Quantum_mechanical_definition).

Comment: When I turn someone else's comment verbatim into an answer, I mark the answer community wiki so that I don't get credit for it.

Answer (score 1):

Quantum mechanics tends to *quantize* things, forbidding certain "continuous" solutions that would otherwise exist in favor of "discrete" solutions. Whenever those discrete solutions exist, you can assign some integer "quantum numbers" to a system and view solutions as an overlay of those numbers.

A simple answer where they don't exist is if you have the potential $V = 0$, which gives us free-particle wavefunctions in 3D space; you can get normalized Gaussian wavepackets travelling through this potential, but there is nothing to quantize it unless you make the space "wrap around" in some dimension -- so if you try to do $V = 0$ on a torus you might have quantized energies again.

Another one, which mixes them, is $V = \{0\text{ if }|x| > L/2,\text{ else } -V_0\}.$ This has some discrete negative energies of "bound states" but also some "travelling waves" with positive energies; the bound states are likely quantized while the travelling ones are likely continuous.

Another example occurs in solid-state systems, where often you've got a quantum dot which interacts with phonons and other complicated systems; often these have a simple effect that they effectively "broaden" the discrete energy levels to a Lorentzian distribution in energy.

Comment: "the bound states are likely quantized while the travelling ones are likely continuous". Does this mean there are bound states that aren't energy quantised?

Comment: @Gert: I do not know how to prove the theorem that spatial confinement of a wavefunction necessarily implies discrete energies, but I also don't have a ready counterexample. It seems somewhat likely, as spatial confinement means that the momentum of the wavefunction must be constantly reflected inwards, which should set up a standing wave, which should quantize. So my gut feeling is 'no' but I don't think I have the skill to prove it.

Comment: I've always believed bound states are energy quantized. It's probably safe to retain this as a likely hypothesis, but maybe hard to actually prove.

Answer (score 1):

No, the easiest example is the spin of a fermion (electron, muon, etc...) which is always half integer.